# ios 8.3 UIWebView loading indicator not dissapearing

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I have a controller with a webview that loads some links. If the link takes some time to load, the webview shows a loading indicator (I don't do it, it is done automatically). If the link does not load, and the user goes back, while he goes to the previous controller, the webview's loading indicator is still active. Any suggestions on how to hide it?

EDIT: image of the indicator I mean:

[Indicator](http://s29.postimg.org/5jh3kw8zb/IMG_0004.png)

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are referring to the indicator in the status bar that shows when there is network activity.  If so, this indicator is controlled by calling

```
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicator=YES|NO;
```

Applications need to manage the indicator.  UIWebView nor the URL loading components of iOS will do this for you.

You should stop a UIWebView instance from continuing to load its view by calling stopLoading.

Comment: Please check the image in the link with the indicator I mean. Thank.s